# I am Struck with this error Typo in component lifecycle method declaration react/no-typos

Tags: reactjs

I am working on `Reactjs` project, I created one Component and named it as Students, In that in `Students.js` one error is showing that is Typo in component lifecycle method declaration  `react/no-typos` I don't know why 
it is showing, So please help me debug this issue.

This is **App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Students from './Students/Students'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Students></Students>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is **App.css**

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

This is **Student.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Students.css';


class Students extends Component {
    Render() {
        return(
            <div className='container'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <h1>Hello</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Students
```

This is **Student.css**

```
There is no css in Student.css
```

Comment: You have written the render method with a capital 'R'. Change it from Render to render

Comment: Now its working Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Component lifecycle methods declaration in react should be camelCased. Otherwise It would be typo. Please make your `Rendor()` method's letter 'R' in lowercase (`render()`) to correct this issue.